# Obtener la clase de un genérico de una lista

Tags: java

Estoy intentando obtener el tipo `Class` de un `List<Student>` para poder deserializar con el método `Serialize#read` que tengo montado el cual funciona pero el IDE no hace más que advertirme de que la asignación no es segura, quiero que lo sea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intentos de obtener el Class de `List<Student>`

```
List<Student>.class // error de sintaxis
List.class // Es el único que me acepta y funciona.
```

Método para deserializar

```
public static <T extends Object> T read(final String fileName, final Class<T> clazz) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)));
    final T data = clazz.cast(ois.readObject());
    ois.close();
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te informo que no existe una manera simple de hacer lo que quieres. Hasta donde he visto, tienes dos maneras de realizar lo que solicitas:

1. Realizar el casteo a genérico y agregar la anotación `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked"). Esto solo le dice al compilador que el casteo es seguro en tiempo de ejecución. Pero sabemos que en tiempo de ejecución los genéricos son eliminados, por ende esta estrategia solo elimina la advertencia del compilador.
2. Crear un método para castear la lista. El método es simple:

   ```
   public static <T> List<T> castList(List<?> list, Class<T> clazz) {
       List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
       for (Object o : list) {
           newList.add(clazz.cast(o));
       }
       return newList;
   }
   ```

   O hecho en Java 8 en una sola línea:

   ```
   public static <T> List<T> castListData(List<?> list, Class<T> clazz) {
       return list.stream()
           .map(x -> clazz.cast(x))
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
           ;
   }
   ```

   Y llamas a tu método:

   ```
   return castListData(
       Serialize.read(PATH_DATA, List.class),
       Student.class);
   ```